# Userscript only works if I interact with the page first

Tags: javascript, click, userscripts

I'm trying to automatically click a Login button in Chromium after a particular URL loads.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click()
    }, 4000);
})();
```

If I run `document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click()` in the browser's javascript console, it works.

If I click somewhere on the page in between the page loading and the userscript's click event firing, it works.

But if the browser opens to the page and the script fires without any other interaction, I get a "Login failed" error from the page, which is the same error it would show if the password or username were wrong.  But the password and username were filled in by the browser already.

Initially I tried the https://getautoclicker.com extension and tried all kinds of things like having it fill in the text fields rather than letting the browser do it, but it has exactly the same problem.

How do I simulate whatever happens when the mouse clicks somewhere on the page?

Even if I use `xdotool` to press Ctrl+F between the browser loading the page and the script firing, the script works.

Comment: Figure out the element that takes the initial click and changes the state as a result, then `.click()` it first. Can't really say more without a MCVE

Comment: @CertainPerformance I tried using `.click()` on the text fields, on an h4 header, etc. and it has no effect.  Actually clicking on those with the mouse does have an effect, though, and the script then works.

Comment: I spent hours trying to get this to work, and then used `xdotool` to very kludgily press the button and got a bash script working within a few minutes   I would still like to do it within the browser, though, if possible.

Comment: Yeah, there are some sites that require that sort of interaction. YouTube Studio is one, certain fields cannot be filled automatically with a userscript, at least not that I've found. I tried for hours too. Lower-level automation like at the OS level is sometimes required, like with AutoHotKey

Comment: If the site's code isn't too long, it should be possible to fix by reading it. But if the site's code is long and minified, sometimes you might just be out of luck

Comment: @CertainPerformance It's long and minified and I don't know how to untangle it all.  Yeah, `xdotool` is Linux's AutoHotkey.  Even telling `xdotool` to press Ctrl+F after the browser opens and before the script triggers is enough to allow the script to work.

Comment: maybe you should consider using a password manager extension lastpass or keepass which you can set options to auto login.

Comment: @Comentarist The browser already stores the passwords.  Those extensions can press buttons to login?

Comment: yes, they do. If the user check the AutoLogin checkbox. I personally use LastPass.
[see SO example](http://puu.sh/I7i2Q/810cba1407.png)
It wouldn't work if the site requires captcha for login.